# gnucash crashes (2.6.12-1)

Tags: gnucash

gnucash 2.6.12-1 with Ubuntu 16.04.

This version was installed on May 5th and worked until today when I got an update of metacity (whatever that is).
I have reinstalled gnucash, but the error remains the same.

```
$ gnucash
Found Finance::Quote version 1.38
*** Error in `gnucash': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000056431b7b3960 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f5aa25de725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f5aa25e6f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f5aa25eaabc]
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. As muclux's answer hints that the issue is related to recurring transactions, I gunzipped a copy of the file (renamed with a .gz extension), which gives a XML file, and opened the file in a text editor. Then I removed all

```
<gnc:schedxaction>...</gnc:schedxaction>
```

XML tags (with their content), saved the file, gzipped it, renamed it, and this file can now be opened by GnuCash with no error. In this way, there is no need for GnuCash on Windows to delete the recurring transactions.

Comment: Open tag contain parameters. In text editor search:
<gnc:schedxaction ...</gnc:schedxaction>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, heemayl, for the editing.

I have found the cause of the invalid pointer. Some of the scheduled transactions were corrupted (I don't know how that happened or if it was related to my upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04).

I noticed it when I opened my data file with the windows version of gnucash. After deleting two transactions scheduled for today I sent the data file back to linux. Now I can again open my data file with the linux gnucash.